Terraform Verify Ownership of domain
I am trying to use Terraform to spin up a Cloud DNS managed zone for my domain (popchop.org), however I keep getting this error in the Terraform Apply command where it asks me to verify I own the domain. I click this link and do the steps to add the txt custom record to my domain in Square space like below:
google-site-verification=nzvFGw3thfusT4iQsuVi0GeM3hgVealXgJgoRDhdTtA
However, even after 48 hours I am still unable to apparently verify I own this domain and get the following error:

Also when I try and nslookup for my domain, I can't see anything which I think is unusual:

Any help would be greatly appreciated - I've read around and watched some YouTube videos but still got no idea

You've uploaded 3 images of errors: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors without adding any of the error text to your question. You have also not included any of your Terraform code in your question.

Hi Mark,
See edit now for my terraform code. The error messages are already in the post as screenshots

Please read the link in my comment, for the reason StackOverflow does not accept screenshots of error messages.
